# Argument of a continuos system frecuency response

Tags: homework-and-exercises, complex-systems, linear-systems

Yo there!, I have seen a question in a book that I solved, the way that is defined is what make me curious.

The idea is to prove that the steady state of stable system with transfer function $P(s)$ and a input $u=A \sin\omega t$ is  $A\lvert P(j\omega)\rvert \sin\omega t + \phi$ where $\phi=\arg P(j\omega)$.

This Phi is what I don’t clearly  understand why is this way, i.e. I get that in the waves and control sides this mean how much is out of phase the wave or the closed loop control or the output of a system, so why Phi isn’t defined as the argument of a trigonometric function or some other thing, this is a canonical figure based on Fourier analysis? It would have sense to speak of a $\phi=\cosh P(j\omega)$ in example?

By the way, the problem resolution I’ve done is

- Apply the Laplace transform of the output $$Y(s)=P(s)U(s)=P(s)\frac{A\omega}{(s^2+\omega^2)}$$
- Now, when this is expanded into partial fraction, there will be terms due poles of $P(s)$ and $u$. Since is a stable system the functions based on the poles of P(s) goes to zero in the infinite, so it remains the poles of the input in the expansion.$$Y_{\infty}(s)=\frac{AP(j\omega)}{2j(s-j\omega)}+\frac{AP(-j\omega)}{-2j(s+j\omega)}$$
- Aplying the inverse Laplace transform
  $$Y_{\infty}=A\lvert P(j\omega) \rvert \frac{e^{j\omega t}e^{j\phi}-e^{-j\omega t}e^{-j\phi}}{2j}=A\lvert P(j\omega)\rvert \sin\omega t + \phi$$

That fits whit the description, but why this $\phi$?